# Confusion with my MYSQL connect_timeout units

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a bit of code to support an alexa front end.
It runs on Rpi, it's python querying a mysql db, flask-ask etc.

It works perfectly all day long, the following morning I get an error 2006 (mysql has gone away) error and have to restart the python script.

I checked my config and connect_timeout = 10.

I assumed this was hours but seems to be defined as seconds....so I can't understand how my code works all day long and only fails after a nights sleep.  I'm certainly not running queries every 10 seconds.

I've found the ping command and wanted to try it to reestablish the connection, but testing is a bit of a pain if you have to go to bed between each test, so I really wanted to set the timeout to 10 seconds so I can reproduce the error at will and test the ping.

Any clues how I can make it timeout after a few seconds?

Comment: I would ask a few questions about what your code is doing: (1) *how often* is our code querying the server? Is it not supposed to be making any queries at night? (2) Have you tried monitoring the server overnight and keeping track of whether it has outages longer than 10 seconds? (3) Does it tend to fail at a specific timestamp at night, or is it random?

Comment: Thanks....the code is triggered by an alexa voice command, so how often it runs is totally unpredictable...when i'm testing its every few mins, but when its "live" it could go weeks without a request.  The server is fine all night, its just sitting waiting....it only gives error 2006 when it gets the first request of the following day, i guess after > x minutes/hours of no sql running.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different timeout parameters in mysql, for example :

- [connect_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) - defaults to 10 seconds

> The number of seconds that the mysqld server waits for a connect packet before responding with Bad handshake.

- [max_execution_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time) - unlimited by default

> The execution timeout for SELECT statements, in milliseconds. If the value is 0, timeouts are not enabled.

- [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) - defaults to 8 hours

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive connection before closing it.

- [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) - timeout) - defaults to 8 hours

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it.

You would need to investigate which timeout is causing issues in your use case, and modify it accordingly. Based on your description of the problem, where you explain that connection gets lost overnight while your script is sleeping it could be `wait_timeout` (or `interactive_timeout`, depending on how your connection is initiated).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Any idea how i find out which timeout is causing the problem?  My code is just sitting waiting for an alexa request to come in.  I have added a ping to one of the initial sections of code (i have a few voice commands that can trigger a call to my code with different initial @ask sections).  I can try calling the pinged section first in the morning and see if that fixes it.  i'll also try setting the interactive_timeout to a lower number to see if that helps reproducing the error.  cheers

Comment: Yes, set the wait_timeout (or interactive_timeout) to a low value, that should allow to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If your code is very rarely hit, why not create a new db connection for every hit ? Else, for each request, you could try to ping the database first, and recreate the connection if that fails.