Mysql connector for python appears to be crashing, how can I diagnose the problem?
The following code is expected to print, "A", "B", and "C":
print ("A")
import mysql.connector
print("B")
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="test",
  password="testpass",
)
print("C")

For some reason it prints "A", and "B", but never C. If I change the port to an incorrect port, it gives an error, so it seems to be connecting. I have tried adding a long time-out and that does not help. I have also tried connecting through the mysql command-line, and I am able to connect. I have also tried adding a try{} except{} block; the code never reaches the except block.
What can I do to determine the problem?

no python expert but I guess you simply have to remove the comma behind password="testpass",

@Aaron trailing commas are fine in Python

It seems it tries to connect for a long time. Try connect(...) with get_warnings=True, raise_on_warnings=True, see also timeouts in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152248/confusion-with-my-mysql-connect-timeout-units . You can try more verbose logging with import logging;  logger = logging.getLogger("mysql.connector"); logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG). Maybe you can also start the MySQL server with mysqld --verbose.

Downgrading to mysql-connector-python 9.0.0 seemed to fix this for me.
I was having the same issue where the connection seems to fail and will cause Python to exit silently. In your example, my code would print A, B, and then exit before hitting C. Running the loggers Marcin mentioned would not give me any output.
